# Login Validation?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code, this code should pass the test but if i use wrong credentials it still passes the test even though the credentials is incorrect.

I am new to Selenium WebDriver and am not sure what am doing wrong.

```
public class LoginTest {

    String url ="jdbc:sqlserver://CODESV3;databaseName=Codes;integratedSecurity=true";
    String DBdriver ="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
    Connection conn = null;
    WebDriver driver = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    @BeforeTest
    public void establishConn()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://10.10.10.50/");
        // establish connection 
        try{
            Class.forName(DBdriver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Database failed to connect ");
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin()
    {
        String forceID="1234";
        String username="ayaslem";
        String password="Delpiero10+";
        boolean valueFound=true;
        // Check the db
        try{
            pstmt=conn.prepareCall("select * from Login where ForceID=?, and Username=? and Password=?");
            pstmt.setString(1,forceID);
            pstmt.setString(2,username);
            pstmt.setString(3,password);
            rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            valueFound = rs.next();

        }catch(Exception e){
                // report some error
        }
        System.out.println(valueFound);
        // login into app
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_OrganisationName']")).sendKeys(forceID);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_UserId']")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='LogonModel_Password']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='maincontent']/form/div/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/input")).click();

        String actual_title = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(valueFound);
        if(valueFound){
            Assert.assertEquals( actual_title,"Dashboard");
        }else{
            Assert.assertEquals(actual_title,"Logon");
        }   
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeConn() throws SQLException
    {
        if(conn!=null && !conn.isClosed())
        {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: valueFound = rs.next(); are you sure rs.next() returns false on a query not found? in my experience it will return true with a set of 0 on a query not found

Comment: rs.next checks the next row and valueFound should return true if the  credentials exist in database and if they dont exist valueFound should return false.

Comment: I know what you are 'trying' to do, but rs.next() only returns false if the query is poorly written (ie syntax errors) it will ALWAYS return true if the query is correct (even if the WHERE condition is not satisfied). Your select statement is correctly written, therefore rs.next() returns true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only 2 asserts that might fail your test (apart from any exceptions thrown, of course). So let's just focus on them.

When you provide fake login and password, your `valueFound` variable is set to false and it follows to the else block, where JUnit asserts whether webdriver is still on the logon site. Since your web application that you're testing most likely stayed on the Logon page after logging in with fake credentials, the assert passes (as it checks whether it's still on logon page, by checking the page's title).

When you provide correct login and password, the `if` condition passes, since `valueFound` is set to true after finding such user in the DB and continues on to assert whether Webapp redirected u to the Dashboard page.

I think your test covers both cases well enough, checks if the app stays on current page with fake data, and checks if it navigates forward to dashboard page with real data. It should both pass in my opinion, in both cases.

P.S. Here's a tip - you don't need to  use xpath everywhere. There are dedicated methods such as `By#id(int)` that are there to make your life as an automated test engineer easier :)

Also, using what I call weak xpaths is a really bad practice (`//*[@id='maincontent']/form/div/fieldset/div[4]/div[2]/input`). Should any ordering on the page change, or any element get wrapped in an intermediary div, your xpath will not locate the element u're looking for. Ask Webapp's developers for ID's or Name's, or use `By#tagName("button")` on the form container element.

Comment: Sye, Thanks... This is just a mock example and if my test passes (behaves as i expected) then i transfer it to my data driven framework.

Comment: I believe it does behave like it should to test the application properly. What I did apart from that is provide explanation as to why it passes in both cases. Feel free to accept the answer if you find it helpful :)

Comment: the code is passing even when i have the wrong credentials and am not sure why.

Comment: I know, and I told you exactly why it passes and why it should pass. Please read my answer carefully.